# Blocking acess if are not connected to a determined network

Tags: javascript, network-programming

I want to block a user from submit a form if they are not connected to a specified network. How should i do this? Javascript solution was what i was looking for.

**Example:**

If not connected to my home network you cannot acess the foo page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frontend Javascript cannot get the IP address of a user without using some kind of API.

Two options exist for you there:

1. **Use an API to get the IP address.** ipinfo.io is one I have used in the past, but you have to pay for it if you get any significant number of requests. This particular call just works for demoing it every now and then. Below is some code which checks whether the user is on my home network.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  function getNetworkIP(json) {
    if (json.ip === '108.173.5.106'){
        console.log('The IP address passes the test');
    }
    else{
        console.log('The IP address fails the test');
    }
  }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://ipinfo.io/?format=jsonp&callback=getNetworkIP"></script>
```

2. **You would add some kind of validation on the server side for the submission of the form** that checked if the IP address matched the desired network and reject it if the request did not come from the appropriate network. How you would go about doing this depends on your server side implementation.

Frontend Javascript can be broken by a variety of means (including just turning it off), so I would use the server side one for reasons of security. I've gotten around a heck of a lot of frontend validation.

Comment: So i can do it with php?

Comment: @AlmostDone Almost certainly.

Comment: But my local ip could be equal to your local ip i am correct?

Comment: @AlmostDone it depends on where you are hosting this form if I understand your question correctly.